# Facebook connect para OSClass 3.3.2 no loguea más.

Tags: facebook

Tengo instalado el plugin de Facebook Connect instalado para un OSClass 3.3.2 y después de un tiempo sin haber hecho ningún cambio comprobé que no funciona más. (Antes funcionaba sin problemas) . Simplemente cuando clickeas el boton vuelve a la misma página y no hace nada. Pensé que a lo mejor Facebook cambió algo en su forma de configurar apps, probé configurarla de nuevo pero nada. Alguna idea que puede ser?

Comment: Hola Pablo. Tienes logs con errores o algo asi? Sin más informacion , puede que esta pregunta se cierre como "No relacionado > No reproducible" ... intenta recabar todos los cambios de la version de OSClass asi como errores que puedas ver en tu app. Un saludo

Comment: Por lo que leí, Facebook cambió la API y los desarrolladores no actualizaron ni planean actualizar el plugin.